# MYSQL: stored procedure not executing query correctly with 'IN' clause correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, in-operator

I'm trying to pass a string value to a stored procedure from my code but it is not executing the query correctly. Following is the code of stored procedure.

I want to pass multiple values to the stored procedure like '2,3,4'. But when I do it only takes 2 and throws an error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_INSERT_PROCESSED_ETC_RECORDS_TO_MAIN_TABLE`
(
    IN RECORD_ID VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TX_TOLL_TRANSACTION_RECORD_DETAIL_STAGING 
    WHERE ID IN (RECORD_ID);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function instead of IN operator

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_INSERT_PROCESSED_ETC_RECORDS_TO_MAIN_TABLE`
(
    IN RECORD_ID VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TX_TOLL_TRANSACTION_RECORD_DETAIL_STAGING 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, RECORD_ID);
END
```